# Can I get evicted from my apartment for a late payment in Canada?

Tags: canada, rent, lease

Can I get evicted from my apartment for a late payment in Canada? I think I made a late payment and I received a letter from the Tribunal, because the landlord sent a tribunal request to have my lease cancelled. Do I have to attend the hearing? I think I paid for both months on the third week of the second month. I usually did it on the first of every two months, but I thought it was ok to pay it a little bit late. If I don't attend the hearing, can I get evicted? Because I can't defend myself other than admit that I paid late and I don't see the point of doing that.

I just paid the rent for January and February just now, but yeah I am not sure what's the point of this. Although I don't mind paying in advance, I just didn't feel like it.

Comment: I assume you mean "the landlord sent a tribunal request" not "the renter" since you appear to be the renter in this situation and, presumably, you aren't asking to have your lease cancelled.

Comment: I read it was ok as long as I paid, but I am not sure what the tribunal hearing is for, it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: "Because I can't defend myself other than admit that I paid late and I don't see the point of doing that": if the landlord alleges that you didn't pay your rent, then there is a very good reason to assert that you paid late.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If I don't attend the hearing, can I get evicted?

Yes. Never ignore a court hearing date. The Tribunal could otherwise impose an outcome without hearing your side of the story. If you ultimately paid the rent and the late fees, and the Tribunal didn't know that, you could be unjustly evicted if you don't present your side of the story.

It could simply be a case, for example, where the landlord confused your non-payment with someone else's. But after the Tribunal rules, fixing that mistake is much more difficult than fixing it at a hearing.

It could be that making two late payments that are cured later is still grounds for eviction under the lease, although I very much doubt it. In that case, it still pays to show up to make sure that the Tribunal has all of the facts favorable to you before it makes its decision.